# Solve $\textbf y'=A\textbf y$ with $\textbf y\in \mathbb R^4$ and $A\in \text{Mat}(4\times 4,\mathbb R)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> We consider
>   $$\textbf y'(t)=A\textbf y(t)$$
>   with $\textbf y(0)=\textbf y_0\in \mathbb R^4$ and $A\in \text{Mat}(4\times 4,\mathbb R)$. Let $\textbf y_1,\textbf y_2,\textbf y_3,\textbf y_4\in\mathbb R^4$ linearly independant and $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2\neq \lambda_3\in\mathbb C$ s.t.
>   $$A\textbf y_1=\lambda_1\textbf y_1$$
>   $$A\textbf y_2=\lambda_2\textbf y_2$$
>   $$A\textbf y_3=\lambda_3\textbf y_3$$
>   $$(A-\lambda_3)\textbf y_4=\textbf y_3.$$
>
> Write the solution $\textbf y(t)$ in function of $\textbf y_0, \textbf y_i$ and $\lambda_i$. Give a condition such that $$\limsup_{t\to\infty }\textbf y(t)<\infty .$$

I agree that $\textbf y_1,\textbf y_2,\textbf y_3$ are eigenvectors and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ eigenvalues, but what can I do with $\textbf y_4$ ? Because I can not diagonalize this matrix. And even if I could, I would like to calculate the $e^A$, but it doesn't look easy since I don't have the change of basis. It's probably not a complicate exercise, but like that, I can't continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $y_4$ you have
$$
(A-\lambda_3I)^2 y_4=0.
$$
You can use this fact and the definition of the matrix exponent to find that
$$
y(t)=e^{\lambda_3 t}(I+(A-\lambda_3I)t)y_4
$$
solve your system. Now you have four linearly independent solutions and hence can write down the general solution.

Here are some additional details.

The task is to calculate $e^{tA}y_4$. Note that you do not need to know $e^{tA}$ to actually calculate the needed expression.

Start with $$e^{tA}y_4=e^{\lambda_3tI-\lambda_3tI+tA}=e^{\lambda_3 t}e^{t(A-\lambda_3I)}y_4,$$
and finish the calculations using the definition.

Comment: Bravo for your observation that $(A-\lambda_3 I)^2 y_4=0$, very nice :-) Therefore $y_4\in \ker(A-\lambda_3 I)^2$, but I'm sorry, I still not see how to conclude. Can I diagonalize the matrix ? How can I use the exponent ?

Comment: @idm Do you know the definition of the matrix exponent?

Comment: I know it yes. But we always use it on diagonale matrix (because much easier), and the problem is I don't see how to diagonalize this matrix.

Comment: You do not need to diagonalize anything here.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry but I don't understand what you do. Why do you only calculate $e^{tA}y_4$ ? (the matrix exponential is very new for me, I don't know all the tricks). If you don't have time, do not worried. Tks :-)

Comment: To write down the general solution you need 4 linearly independent solutions. First three are simple $e^{\lambda_it}y_i$. You need one more. Since by the assumption $y_4$ is linearly independent of the rest, as a fourth solution you can take $e^{tA}y_4$. The only thing is that you do not know $e^{tA}$. But I tried to show you that you do not need to.

Answer (score 1):

here is a nother way to do this. let $y= a_1y_1 + a_2y_2 + a_3y_3 + a_4y_4,$ then $y^\prime = Ay$ turns into $a_1^\prime = \lambda_1 a_1, a_2^\prime = \lambda_2 a_2, a_3^\prime = \lambda_3 + a_4, a_4^\prime = \lambda_3 y_4.$ the solutions are
$$a_1 = a_1(0)e^{\lambda_1t},
 a_2 = a_2(0)e^{\lambda_2t},
 a_3 = (a_3(0) + ta_4(0))e^{\lambda_3t},
 a_4 = a_4(0)e^{\lambda_3t}$$

therefore the solution is $$ y = ae^{\lambda_1t}+
 be^{\lambda_2t}+
 (c + d + td)e^{\lambda_3t} \text { where }a, b, c, d \text{ are constants.}$$

the condition for existence for all $t> 0$ is that all eigenvalues be negative.